# Cannot read property 'getRange' of null error. I am positive the sheet exists and is named correctly in the script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My fellow teachers and I like to send students little google drawings to let them know they've been doing well lately. We have a spreadsheet that we use and I am trying to automate the process of sending them an email when their drawing is ready to be viewed. I keep getting the 'Cannot read property 'getRange' of null error' even though I am 100% sure that a sheet exists with the name PR and that it is spelled right. I am new to Google Script so I lack the skills to troubleshoot any more than the googling I've done already, which basically just says to make sure you've named the sheet correctly. Any help would be very appreciated!

````
  var studentFirstNameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("A2:A"); 
  var studentFirstname = studentFirstNameRange.getValues();
  var studentEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("D2:D"); 
  var studentEmail = studentEmailRange.getValues();
var emailSendRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("L2:L"); 
  var emailSend = emailSendRange.getValues();
  if (emailSend){
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Hi ' + studentFirstname + '! Your teachers noticed you have been doing a great job this year, so we made this for you! Keep up the great work!' ; // Second column
    var subject = 'Positive Recognition';
    MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail, subject, message);
    }
}```
````

Comment: what are the informations located in column L?

Comment: Your code can't work the way it's written.  `emailSend` is a 2 dimensional array of values and cannot return a boolean. In addition your missing a function declaration.  If you wish to use indeterminate ranges then you must filter the nulls at the end.

Comment: Can you confirm that this code is bound to the spreadsheet that has the sheet 'PR'? i.e., Did you create the code by using Tools > Script Editor (or Extensions > Apps Script) from that same spreadsheet?

Comment: And it looks like you've posted only a portion of your script function.  If that's the case can you post the whole thing?  Or even better if you can share a copy of the spreadsheet in question.

Comment: @howsthebrand : do you need any other help?

Comment: It wasn't bound to the sheet  thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the title and the error you related, I did'nt get any error.

However, I don't understand your condiiton `if (emailSend)` neither the way you send emails. If you send emails to all the population at once, you can try

```
function myFunction() {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getLastRow()
  var studentFirstNameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("A2:A"+lastRow); 
  var studentFirstname = studentFirstNameRange.getValues();
  var studentEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("D2:D"+lastRow); 
  var studentEmail = studentEmailRange.getValues();
  var emailSendRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("L2:L"+lastRow); 
  var emailSend = emailSendRange.getValues();
  if (emailSend){
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Hi ' + studentFirstname + '! Your teachers noticed you have been doing a great job this year, so we made this for you! Keep up the great work!' ; // Second column
    var subject = 'Positive Recognition';
    Logger.log(studentEmail.join())
    MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail.join(), subject, message);
  }
  console.log('there is no errors!')
}
```

if you want to send individually

```
function myFunction() {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getLastRow()
  var studentFirstNameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
  var studentFirstname = studentFirstNameRange.getValues();
  var studentEmailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("D2:D" + lastRow);
  var studentEmail = studentEmailRange.getValues();
  var emailSendRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PR').getRange("L2:L" + lastRow);
  var emailSend = emailSendRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < studentFirstname.length; i++) {
    if (emailSend[i][0]) {
      // Send Alert Email.
      var message = 'Hi ' + studentFirstname[i][0] + '! Your teachers noticed you have been doing a great job this year, so we made this for you! Keep up the great work!'; // Second column
      var subject = 'Positive Recognition';
      MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail[i][0], subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]